# Can't change element attribute inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple drawing application in javascript. One requirement is to resize to canvas according to the page, anyways, heres a simplified reproduction of the problem:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("fencemaker");
var mainDivCS = window.getComputedStyle(mainDiv);
var topCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
topCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "gray"; 
mainDiv.appendChild(topCanvas);     

someFunction();

function someFunction() {
    topCanvas.Width = 100;
    topCanvas.Height = 100;
}
```

I can change the width and height if i put the changes right after creating the element but inside the function they do nothing. If I put "alert(topCanvas.width);" in the function after changing the value, it returns the correct value (100) but still draws wrong (defaults to 300). Whats going on here?

tested in opera 12 and chrome 35

Comment: Try `topCanvas.width = 100`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. Try `width` and `height`, lowercase.

Comment: Although you got an answer in the comments, please accept the answer below to mark this Q as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that you need to use lowercase for `width` and `height`. So you should have:

```
function someFunction() {
    topCanvas.width = 100;
    topCanvas.height = 100;
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Cc47/